# p:menuitem action equivalent in DefaultMenuItem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to write a p:menuitem action equivalent in DefaultMenuItem?

I want to write the following in java code:

```
<p:menuitem value="Perfiles" action="utilerias/perfiles"/>
```

DefaultMenuItem does not have a setAction method. setCommand and setUrl does not have the same behavior as p:menuitem action.

```
DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem("Perfiles");
menuItem.setCommand("utilerias/perfiles"); // not the same as p:menuitem action
```

I get the jsf page path string from a database.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to create a method that recieves the name of the page and return it as String and set it as the menuItem command:

```
DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem("Perfiles");
menuItem.setCommand("#{menuBean.page('utilerias/perfiles')}");
subMenu.addElement(menuItem);
```

Having the method in the bean:

```
public String page(String page) {
   return page;
}
```